# UIView rounded corners with PatternImage

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiview, cornerradius

Here, cornerRadius is not working with PatternImage, Could you please help me?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    myView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
    myView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clip your view or the background will bleed out.

```
myView.layer.maskToBounds = YES;
```

You could also use the UIView method, but I figured you were already in the layer so it would look cleaner that way haha. They do the same thing.

```
myView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```